# issue in width of divs and its borders

Tags: css, html, width, border

I'am newbie in css, I want to discuss this question with you:

suppose that we have a div named A and its width = X px, and we have also 2 divs inside it, div B and div C.

div B:

```
width: 20%;
border: 1px;
```

div C:

```
width: 80%;
border: 1px;
```

so that, the summation of width of these 2 divs is as follow:

`20% + 80% + 2(1px left border + 1px right border) => 100% (" width of div A) + 4px`

the question is how to make the width of B and C equal to the width A regardless how its the width of their borders?

Comment: You're looking for [`box-sizing: border-box;`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) - also note that FF [still requires](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing) the `-moz` prefix for this property to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), the `borders`, `paddings` and `margins` are counted outside of the element, inorder to count the `border` inside, as you need, you have to use
[`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property with a value of `border-box`.

[**Demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/8fEmt/) (Normal)

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/8fEmt/1/) (Using `box-sizing`)

Answer (score 0):

I assume either B or C have the `float` attribute.
In that case, skip the `width`-specification from the non-floating div. It will automagically fill up the rest of the width and fit snugly to the border of A.